# Node.js MSSQL 500: Internal Error. Details: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to DESKTOP-LK9JDJJ:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.99.1:1433

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, npm

settings.js

```
exports.dbConfig = {
user: "gpolat",
password: "alphalpha",
server: "DESKTOP-LK9JDJJ",
database: "mydemo",
port: 1433
};
exports.webPort = 9000;
```

db.js

```
var sqlDb = require("mssql");
var settings = require("../settings");

exports.executeSql = function (sql, callback) {

var conn = new sqlDb.Connection(settings.dbConfig);
conn.connect()
    .then(function () {
        var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);
        req.query(sql)
            .then(function (recordset) {
                callback(recordset);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback(null, err);
            });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(null, err);
    });

};
```

Console Error:

```
Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:5858
Started Listening at: 9000
{ ConnectionError: Failed to connect to DESKTOP-LK9JDJJ:1433 - connect 
ECONNREFUSED 192.168.99.1:1433
at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gokhan\documents\visual studio 
2015\Projects\SampleREST\SampleREST\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:378:25)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:290:19)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\Gokhan\documents\visual studio 
Projects\SampleREST\SampleREST\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:531:1
4)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1281:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
name: 'ConnectionError',
message: 'Failed to connect to DESKTOP-LK9JDJJ:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 
192.168.99.1:1433',
code: 'ESOCKET' }
```

I get this error while creating the rest API via sql server.
"500: Internal Error. Details: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to DESKTOP-LK9JDJJ:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.99.1:1433"

Comment: Have you tried temporarily disabling Windows Firewall on DESKTOP-LK9JDJJ?

Comment: I tried but not.